# How can I set my parameters when I am doing a post?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Post")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(int adminTestId)
```

I am sending the following but it's giving me an error:

```
POST /api/UserTest/Post

    body {"adminTestId":1197}
```

Can someone tell me how I can set the parameter to the method so it will accept adminTestId?

Here is the message that I am getting:

{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:3048/api/UserTest/Post'.","messageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'UserTest' that matches the request."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are setting the incorrect route:

```
[Route("UsetTest/Post")]
```

This is assuming `api/` is the correct prefix.

Answer (score 0):

In Web API, requests are mapped to actions based on HTTP verbs.

Therefore, you should not include **Post** in your URL which defeats the purpose of using Web API and violate REST rules.

### Post Json

If you want to post json, you want to bind to a model.

[image]

[image]

### Post Integer

If you just want to accept an single integer value, you just post an integer instead of json.

[image]

[image]